# heroku run rake db:migrate:status down in heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

When i run heroku run rake db:migrate:status

I have the last four migration down like this

```
 up     20150916190326  Add fields to purchase
   up     20150923012744  Create friendly id slugs
   up     20150923013732  Add weight to product
   up     20150926012254  Add stste to purchase
   up     20150930015516  Add shipping rate to purchase
  down    20150930025547  Add country to purchase
  down    20150930025742  Add country again to purchase
  down    20150930031326  Add countryy to purchase
  down    20150930042706  Add countryyy to purchase
```

what should i run to make it all of them up but without deleting my database in heroku?

Comment: i suggest you to edit the question and add `migration` along with result of `heroku run rake db:migrate:status`. Give us as much info as feasible to let us help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Step 1) Check version numbers of migrations that  are down by using the below command.

heroku run rake db:migrate:status

Step 2) Below command will migrate the table  with respective version numbers.

```
 heroku run rake db:migrate:up VERSION= 20150930025547
```

Comment: Super small addition to that point above, but there shouldn't be any space between the version and the number. In this example, should be `VERSION=20150930025547`